# Output the answer once when done, not on every line

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, count

I run the following script and it prints the output for every line in file, but I need output the answer once when done, not on every line. Anyone please help me

```
const fs = require("fs");
const readline = require("readline");
const stream = require("stream");

const filename = process.argv[2];
const instream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
const outstream = new stream();
outstream.readable = true;
outstream.writable = true;

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: instream,
  output: outstream,
  terminal: false,
});
const obj = {};
rl.on("line", function (line) {
  const [country] = line.split(",", 1);
  {
    for (let i = 0; i < [country].length; i++)
      if (obj[country] != null) {
        obj[country] += 1;
      } else {
        obj[country] = 1;
      }
  }
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `close` event, This event is called after the read stream is closed and has been processed.

```js
rl.on("close", function (line) {
  console.log(obj);
});
```